# I am trying to change the value of a number if the new value isnt the reverse of the old value

Tags: lua

i have tried many things but my code is not working
here is the code

```
function mxy(x,y,p)
 correctX = 0
 correctY = 0
 if p.mx == x or p.mx ~= -x then correctX = 1 end
 if p.my == y or p.my ~= -y then correctY = 1 end
 if correctX and correctY then p.mx = x  p.my = y end
end
```

"p" is a list
p.my and p.mx are the old values
the function inputs "x" and "y" are the new values

this code is made in lua

Answer (score 4):

In lua only **nil** and **false** will be evaluated as false, so the condition `correctX and correctY` is always true. You could correct it by using boolean values.

```
correctX = false
if p.mx == x or p.mx ~= -x then correctX = true end
```

Answer (score 0):

Lua will not assume the int you are dealing with as a boolean if it is 0 or 1 like many other languages do. Instead, Lua checks if the variable is nil or false.

Here's a more clear explanation comparing c++ and lua:
For c++: bool(NULL)=false, bool(0)=false, bool(1)=true, bool(2)=true, etc..
For lua: bool(nil)=false,  bool(0)=true,  bool(1)=true, bool(2)=true, etc..

Your code can be simplified to:

```
function mxy(x, y, p)
    if (p.mx == x or p.mx ~= -x) and (p.my == y or p.my ~= -y) then
        p.mx = x
        p.my = y
    end
end
```